# What is the best way to fetch values from Custom Metadata?

Tags: custom-metadata

Select MasterLabel, Inactive_Email__c from InactiveUsers__mdt

Comment: Please add more description on your question. You could mention what you're trying to achieve, what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

- We are using soql query to return custom meta data earlier.
- In Spring 21, we can access custom meta data without using soql
  Query.
- We can use the  Apex getAll(),  getInstance(recordId),
  getInstance(qualifiedApiName),  and  getInstance(developerName)
  methods to retrieve information from custom metadata type records
  faster.
- These methods don’t rely on the SOQL engine and return the sObject details directly from the call.

In your example, you can use Like below

```
    List<InactiveUsers__mdt> mcs = InactiveUsers__mdt.getall().values();
```

Salesforce document Link :

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_dev_cmt.htm&type=5&release=230

Comment: If you copy and paste from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_dev_cmt.htm&type=5&release=230), you need to clearly mark it as a quote and link to the document.

Comment: thanks for correction.Updated my answer